# Obtain classes and fucntions' import path faster

Tags: python, function, class, import, module

A newbie here who just started learning Python.

I struggle sometimes to remember to entire path to write in order to import a class or function from modules or sub-modules.

For example : I want to run the ADF test, I know it is somewhre in the statsmodels package, but I can't remember that it's located in "from statsmodels.tsa.stattools".

Is there a tool that makes easy to find classes & functions ? Where I could just type "adfuller" and it provides me with different pathes to import it ?

I googled but couldn't find any tool that does this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/). The search feature on that page likely will give you a good starting point.

Comment: The statsmodels docs have a search field https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/  (although I liked to old version with search results better than the current popup results, docs are hosted on github)

Comment: the `dots` and the `intellisense` usually get me there.  if i really needed something repeatedly, i guess i would use a snippet in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for the solution. In VSCDODE:

- you need to enable Auto Imports Completion. It is in the bottom right of the screen;

[image: activate auto imports completion]

- then, whenever you start typing the name of a class or a method, the auto-complete will show a list;

[image: autocomplete list]

- the, just select what you want to use and the import statement will be automatically generated;

[image: automatically generated import statement]